# Meaning of "haply of your fault"

Tags: phrase-meaning, poetry

From *Aurora Leigh*:

> Or worse, we'll say. For dogs, unjustly kicked,
>   Yell, bite at need; but if your dramatist
>   (Being wronged by some five hundred nobodies
>   Because their grosser brains most naturally
>   Misjudge the fineness of his subtle wit)
>   Shows teeth an almond's breath, protests the length
>   Of a modest phrase,–' My gentle countrymen,
>   'There's something in it, **haply of your fault**,'–
>   Why then, besides five hundred nobodies,
>   He'll have five thousand, and five thousand more,
>   Against him,–the whole public,–all the hoofs
>   Of King Saul's father's asses, in full drove,–
>   And obviously deserve it.

What is the meaning of "haply of your fault"? Does it mean "perhaps this phrase that you find inappropriate alludes to some of your faults?

I'm not asking for literary criticism. I cannot understand the basic meaning of the phrase.

Comment: The word is hap and the adverb is  haply: by chance. It's marked as archaic. Try the Oxford Dictionary online. It's there. It's also wrapped in a blanket according to that source, in Northern Irish and Scottish, But that doesn't apply here....:)

Comment: @Lambie - yes, I know what "haply" meanis - but what's the meaning of "haply of your fault"?

Comment: Checking Google Books I find 42 instances of [Shows teeth an almond's breath](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Shows+teeth+an+almond%27s+breath%22) and 46 of [Shows teeth an almond's **breadth**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Shows+teeth+an+almond%27s+breadth%22). My money's on the former being a misprint, since I can't see how [cyanide poisoning](https://symptomchecker.webmd.com/multiple-symptoms?symptoms=bitter-almond-odor-on-breath&symptomids=401&locations=7) is relevant to the text, but the niggled dramatist's metaphorically bared teeth could look like almonds.

Comment: I have no technical explanation for the "genitive" but it does appear in earlier centuries. But I'm seeing different punctuation: "There's something in it, haply, of your fault," In other words, maybe it is your fault, my gentle countrymen. And also am seeing: almond's breadth like FumbleFingers. How cute to say a dog's bared teeth look like peeled almonds. Think about that, they really do.

Comment: @Lambie [Think about that also really do masters of fronting.](https://theweek.com/articles/442256/why-strangely-yoda-speaks) :)

Comment: @tchrist I see no rapport to Yoda-speak at all here. About 150 years too early.

Comment: Since I was about to suggest that *haply* meant *perhaps* I support Lambie's *maybe it is your fault*…